# Android LiveWallpaper animate draw

Tags: java, android, animation, live-wallpaper

Is there a solution I can use to animate each letter before drawing them to a canvas??? Iv search the internet and I don't seem to see anything reasonable...

```
private void draw() {
        SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
        Canvas canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            if (canvas != null) {

                // Draw background
                canvas.drawColor(PrefService.getBgColor());                                  

                StaticLayout textLayout = new StaticLayout(TEXT_I_WOULD_LIKE_TO_ANIMATE, textPaint, screenWidth - screenWidth / 8, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1.0F, 1.0F, true);
                canvas.translate((screenWidth / 2) - (textLayout.getWidth() / 2), (screenHeight / 2) - ((textLayout.getHeight() / 2)));
                textLayout.draw(canvas);
            }
        } finally {
            if (canvas != null) {              
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);                   
            }
        }
    }
    handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
    handler.postDelayed(drawRunner, 20000);
}
```

Note the TEXT_I_WOULD_LIKE_TO_ANIMATE variable above in StaticLayout

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Create a rendering thread in wich you loop you draw method. Then you can make the position for the text variable and change the position of the text wich each frame. And to draw text on a canvas you should use canvas.drawText(...).
I hope i could help you.